# PHP how to retrieve remote ip address?

Tags: php

My scenario is I have binded one ip address with my local ip address i.e. AAA.BBB.CCC.DDD binded to XXX.YYY.ZZZ.AAA

Local  IP: XXX.YYY.ZZZ.AAA 
Remote IP: AAA.BBB.CCC.DDD

I have binded Remote IP to my Local Ip.

So my question is what if I have to get binded Remote Ip address using REMOTE_ADDR method instead of Local (my real) ip address.

Right now it is returning my local ip address.

Please help...

Comment: Ya I am also facing same issue. Please any one help me out.

Comment: see>>> http://blackbe.lt/advanced-method-to-obtain-the-client-ip-in-php/

Answer (score 1):

Use   `$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]` like this

```
$remoteIp = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
if (array_key_exists('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR', $_SERVER)) {
    $remoteIp = array_pop(explode(',', $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']));
}
```

[$_SERVER in php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)